# Is Picard's disease the cause of the time jumping in "All Good Things..."?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode "All Good Things..." of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, Picard is seen jumping through time, but being himself at different ages, so it is not a normal time jump where his body moves back and forward in time.

It is mentioned that he was suffering from a disease. Was that disease the cause of the time jumps or having the effect on his memory that appears like time jumps?

Comment: Q caused the time jumps. The disease in the future just caused people not to believe him/ think he was crazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No, Q is responsible for the time jumping.

He confirms this after being confronted by Picard:

> **PICARD**: Are you responsible for my shifting through time?
> **Q**: I'll answer that question if you promise you won't tell anyone. (in Picard's ear) Yes.

[(TNG: All Good Things...)](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/277.htm)